# Real World Haskell Chapter 3 excercise: Binary Tree with 1 value constructor

Tags: haskell

Chapter 3 defines the following recursive type to represent a binary tree:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty
              deriving (Show)
```

The exercise requires I implement the same type using a single value constructor, using the "Maybe" type to refer to child nodes:

(From Chapter 3 Exercise 2 on page 60)

"Define a tree type that has only one constructor, like our Java example. Instead of the Empty constructor, use the Maybe type to refer to a node's children."

The solution I came up with is the following:

```
data AltTree a = AltNode a (Maybe (AltTree a)) (Maybe (AltTree a))
                 deriving (Show)
```

However, this does not allow for a tree containing other empty trees, such as:

```
AltNode 1 (AltNode 2 Nothing Nothing) (AltNode 3 Nothing Nothing)
```

And I'm not sure why, is "Nothing" not a value constructor for the "Maybe" type?

Comment: Online: [RWH > Chapter 3 > Exercises](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#id585938)

Answer (score 8):

It's not the `Nothing` value constructor which causes your error. You two branches you pass to the top-level tree should have type `Maybe (AltTree a)`, but both `(AltNode 2 Nothing Nothing)` and `(AltNode 3 Nothing Nothing)` have type `AltTree Int`. You have to use `Just` value constructor to create values of `Maybe` type from them. Like

```
AltNode 1 (Just (AltNode 2 Nothing Nothing)) (Just (AltNode 3 Nothing Nothing))
```

Comment: @rr Also, the solution is incomplete - you have no equivalent for `Empty`.  You need to allow `AltNode Nothing Nothing Nothing`.  That still isn't quite right, because now the type system can allow empty nodes that have children.  Perhaps wrapping all the arguments into a Maybe tuple will be semantically better?

Comment: @Matajon, thanks for the explanation, that makes sense now. But does this not make the type different from the implementation they give in the book? Or perhaps I'm reading into this too much.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson That's a good point, I'm not entirely sure, I'll have to play around with it. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson: that's how I would solve this, plus then you can use a `newtype` instead of `data`.  The wording of the question implies the OP's answer though.

Comment: Sadly @ThomasM.DuBuisson's doubt about the impossibility of creating an empty `Tree` has remained unaddressed for years. I will maybe post a question for this specific detail.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Not sure what you mean by my "doubt about the impossibility of..."  - I never said anything about an impossibility.   SPOILER: The solution is to write the entire set of values in a maybe, such as `data AN a = AN (Maybe (a,AN a,AN a))`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm sorry for the bad wording. I meant that **given the solution proposed in this answer** one cannot instantiate an empty `Tree` (but only one with empty children). This is what you meant with your comment 8 years ago, isn't it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Ah yes I see.  That is what I meant.  If it isn't apparent to you, or surprising me with a contradiction, then that is worth a question.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, fyi, I have posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312801/real-world-haskell-chapter-3-excercise-binary-tree-with-1-value-constructor-f); it'd be nice if you could give a look at it.