# Real World Haskell Chapter 3 excercise: Binary Tree with 1 value constructor - follow up

Tags: haskell, tree, option-type

**This question is not a duplicate**

[A question with the same title already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613871/real-world-haskell-chapter-3-excercise-binary-tree-with-1-value-constructor), but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614006/5825294) only partially addressed it, in my opinion, and I am interested also in what it left unaswered.

**Foreword**

Real World Haskell proposes, in Chapter 3, page 58, the following definition for a binary tree datatype,

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty
              deriving (Show)
```

which provides two constructors (for empty and non-empty `Tree`s).

On the other hand, at page 60, an exercise challenges the reader to define the `Tree` datatype by using a single constructor.

After several attempts, I came up with the same solution as the one linked above:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Maybe (Tree a)) (Maybe (Tree a)) deriving(Show)
```

**What is unanswered in the linked question**

The drawback of this definition is that it does not allow the instantiation of an empty `Tree`, although it allows the instantiation of a `Tree` with empty children through the following syntax:

```
Node 3 Nothing (Just (Node 2 Nothing Nothing))
```

I think that there's not much a better solution than the above, if not having a "standalone" empty tree is acceptable and the requirement is to use one constructor only.

Having some comment on the above statement would be nice; however, my main question is how can I define `Tree` with one constructor such that I can instantiate an empty `Tree`?

Now that I've written the question, I think that one possible answer is the following, of which I am not at all sure:

*If a children being empty or not is encoded in whether it is costructed through `Nothing` or `Just (Node ...)`, pretty much the same holds for the whole tree (or root node), which can be indeed defined itself as a `Nothing` or `Just (Node ...)`; this is to say that with only one constructor, `Nothing` is the way to instanciate an empty tree. (In other words, I'm just starting to think that this question is inherently "ill-formed". Notheless I'll post it, as I think I can learn something your comments/answers.)*

Does the above make any sense?

**A possible answer**

A comment in the original question proposes the following solution

```
data Tree a = Tree (Maybe (a,Tree a,Tree a))
```

which (my understanding) allows to instantiate an emtpy tree by `Node Nothing`, or a non-empty tree by `Node (Just (value,child1,child2))`.

Comment: `data Tree a = Tree (Maybe (a,Tree a,Tree a))` seems to be appointing `Nothing` to `Empty` and `Just` to `Node` in the original definition. What exactly it is good for..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: you can turn any n-ary constructor into a 1-ary one using a n-tuple type.

For instance, your tree type is isomorphic to the following one:

```
data Tree a = Node (a, Tree a, Tree a)
            | Empty
```

I think you should now be able to turn this type into one which only involves one constructor.

Comment: I think you are referring to the solution which I've just included in my answer. Even if it is effective, I found it a bit "clunky".

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Ah, right. I missed that. What's clunky about it? I don't think there's another easy way. From a type-theoretic point of view, the standard tree definition is `Tree a = 1 + (a * Tree a * Tree a)` where `+` denotes a sum type, `*` a product type, `1` a unit type. In Haskell, that translates to `Tree a = Either () (a, Tree a, Tree a)` and `Either ()` is best written as `Maybe`.

Comment: My level of type theory is pretty low (if not zero), so I will probably come back to this comment of yours at some point in the future.

Comment: However, it would be great if you could clarify the last part: _`Either ()` is best written as `Maybe`_; my understanding is that both `Maybe` and `Either ()` are type ctors taking 1 concrete type `a` to produce either a value of type `a` wrapped in _something_, or _somethingelse_, where _something_ is `Just` for `Maybe` and `Right` for `Either`, and _somethingelse_ is `Nothing` for `Maybe` and `Left ()` for `Either ()`. So they look two different things to me (even though they can encode the same information).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis What you wrote is correct. They are two distinct types, but they encode the same information. In type theory we say that these are isomorphic, since there are two functions `f :: Maybe a -> Either () a` and `g :: Either () a -> Maybe a` which are mutual inverses. In many cases, we don't really distinguish between the two because of this reason. In practice, in Haskell it's unusual to use `Either () a`, since `Maybe a` can do the same job and is conceptually simpler to understand. It's only a matter of taste, in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @chi alongside his comments says all, it could be done with either as:

```
data Tree a = T (Either () (a, Tree a, Tree a)) deriving Show
```

And an example of a tree is:

```
node1 = T $ Right ("data node 1", node2, node3)
node2 = T $ Left ()
node3 = T $ Right ("data node 3", node2, node2)

  $> node1
T (Right ("data node 1",T (Left ()),T (Right ("data node 3",T (Left ()),T (Left ())))))
```

But everybody already also said, that can be replaced with Maybe, because `Either ()` can be seen as `Maybe a`

Comment: Why are you posting an answer that just restates what others have said?

Comment: @chepner to summarise and condense it all in an answer